# How to get my selected data From the BottomSheetDialogFragment in android?

Tags: android

**Explanation:** I am using a BottomSheetDialogFragment in my application.In which When i click on button which lies in my fragment then bottomSheetDialog show at the bottom of my android phone screen.

The purpose is to create a dialog is to filter my list. So, i put all the required filter data into the dialog and when i select my data the click on apply button dialog is dismiss.Until now everything is working fine. I want to know how to get dialog selected data into my fragment? Based on that i want to apply my list data.

**BottomSheetFragment.java**

```
public class BottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    View contentView;
    Button btnApply;

//    public static BottomSheetFragment newInstance(int num){
//        BottomSheetFragment dialogFragment = new BottomSheetFragment();
//        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//        bundle.putInt("num", num);
//        dialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
//        return dialogFragment;
//    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        contentView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, null);

        btnApply=(Button)contentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_apply);
        btnApply.setOnClickListener(this);

        dialog.setContentView(contentView);
        return dialog;
    }

//    @Override
//    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
//        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
//        contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, null);
//        dialog.setContentView(contentView);
//
//        btnApply=(Button)contentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_apply);
//        btnApply.setOnClickListener(this);
//    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId()==R.id.btn_apply){
//            Intent intent = new Intent();
//            intent.putExtra("ABC", "Ok");
//            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Apply Button Clicked!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

For more See cricbuzz Android application and click on the bell icon. I want exactly like this.

Comment: add your dialog code

Comment: you can make a static method inside fragment and and call it inside the onCLick

Comment: If i want to get the my dialog selected data into my Activity then what?

Comment: you can make it the same way

Comment: I didn't get you.